# How to retrive image from didReceiveIQ method of xmmpframework?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, xmppframework

I want to retrieve `UIImage` from [xmmpframework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)which is send by other person by chat same way like whatsapp  but how can i get `UImage` from that. If image is recived then `didReceiveIQ` method is called but i don't know how to revive `UIImage` from that.

can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you receive image in - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message methio

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya Thanks for reply, but didReceiveMessage is not called when i received image . if i receive image then didReceiveIQ is called and if i receive message (text) then didReceiveMessage called.

Comment: please check this http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0231.html is helping you some thing.

Comment: check the ans. of rahul nair http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524475/sending-image-using-xmpp-framework-on-iphone

Comment: I have checked that but it's not proper way to implement image send/receive. and also it will be slow as compared to IQ method.

Comment: about xep-0231 i don't know how to use. it will be great if you provide me some sample for that. thanks for your constantly reply :) (Y). +1 for you.

Comment: as i have knowledge QI is for only send receive status of user and all other information about users. if image send/receive is done in as per  my first comment receive in that and images or file have to convert in to base64Encoding and than attach to messages

Comment: you can refere as sample code how to send image with message like this in like ans. of Bhrigesh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327203/how-to-transfer-image-one-device-to-another-device-using-xmpp-framework-on-iphon

Comment: When i am sending an image from Spark(local network chat app in Mac) then didReceiveIQ method is called not didMessageReceivedMessage !!!

Comment: @yashesh. i am also searching how to send image using xmpp.can you show some guide or code if you done with this

Comment: @iKrutarth I have done lots of RnD to to achieve Image send/receive functionality using XMPP framework but i didn't get success on it. Finally we have upload an image to our server and we get image URL of that image. After that we send image URL to the receiver and then that image will be download. I guess whatsapp is also doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for Your Guidance,can you please explain in detail how to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get UIImage from XmppFrameowrk, 
then you just need to get the vCard of that user.

If you want to get your image,then you just need to get your own vCard.

Use following method in vCardTemp class of XmppFrameowork:

```
 - (XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTempForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid shouldFetch:(BOOL)shouldFetch
```

Comment: i want image which is send by other person not a profile pic.

Comment: I have implemented the sharing image functionality in IM Chat app like whats app. But I am not sending the image in IQ. I am converting the image into base64Encoded string and send like we send the message. Its working fine. How you are sending the image in IQ? Can you please let me know. When didReceive IQ will call, then we are getting the photo encoded string in photo tag of IQ, you just need to get that tag and get the encoded string.

Comment: I have already successfully implement the image send/receive functionaly by using base64 string , but when i am sending image from my Mac spark(Chat app for local network) to my iPhone app then didReceiveIQ method is called.